# Mongo 3.6.3 java driver aggregate hint - returns undefined field 'hint'

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I am trying to pass a hint on an aggregate in MongoDB Java Driver 3.6.3. The aggregate API allows for adding a hint as in:

```
MongoCollection<Document> coll = database.getCollection("myCollection")
ArrayList<BasicDBObject> docList = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
BasicDBObject hint = new BasicDBObject("$hint","reportjob_customerId_1_siiDocumentAttributes.deleted_1");
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = coll.aggregate(docList).hint(hint).allowDiskUse(batchContext.isAllowDiskUse()).iterator();
```

I've tried with `$hint` and `hint`, but Mongo always returns Command failed with error -1: 'unrecognized field 'hint'

How do I properly send the hint on the aggregate call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is no support to pass the index name directly to hint. So you have pass the index creation document to the hint which you can get by name and use key to get the index document.

```
MongoCollection<Document> coll = database.getCollection("myCollection");
Bson index = coll.listIndexes().into(new ArrayList<>()).stream().filter(item -> item.getString("name").equals("reportjob_customerId_1_siiDocumentAttributes.deleted_1")).findFirst().get().getString("key");
List<BasicDBObject> docList = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = coll.aggregate(docList).hint(index).allowDiskUse(batchContext.isAllowDiskUse()).iterator();
```

Legacy driver had support for both index name and document.

```
MongoClient client =  new MongoClient();
DB database = client.getDB("myDatabase");
DBCollection coll = database.getCollection("myCollection");
List<BasicDBObject> docList = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
AggregationOptions options = AggregationOptions.builder().allowDiskUse(batchContext.isAllowDiskUse()).build();
DBCursor dbCursor = ((DBCursor) coll.aggregate(docList, options)).hint("reportjob_customerId_1_siiDocumentAttributes.deleted_1");
```

You can create a jira to have the option to pass index name in the new driver [`here`](https://jira.mongodb.org/projects/JAVA/summary)

Comment: I tried to do it as you suggested, but I still get the same error.  Also I had to make a change to get the "key" as an object not as a string.  Bson index = coll.listIndexes().into(new ArrayList<>()).stream().filter(item -> item.getString("name").equals("reportjob_customerId_1_siiDocumentAttributes.deleted_1")).findFirst().get().get("key");

Comment: You are right about the key being object.Sorry about that. Did you pass the index to the hint method directly ? Can I see rest of your updated code ?

Comment: I broke out your code into multiple lines for debugging purposes:
`code`
        ArrayList<Document> indexList = new ArrayList<>();
        coll.listIndexes().into(indexList);
        Document indexDocument = indexList.stream().filter(item -> item.getString("name").equals("reportjob_customerId_1_siiDocumentAttributes.deleted_1")).findFirst().get();
        Bson index  = new BasicDBObject((Document)indexDocument.get("key"));
        MongoCursor<Document> cursor = coll.aggregate(docList).hint(index).allowDiskUse(batchContext.isAllowDiskUse()).iterator();

Comment: I was just informed our server is still running MongoDB 3.4, so this may not work until the DBAs upgrade to 3.6.

Comment: You are right. You require 3.6. Just tested. Reference [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-9854)